# Unity Sprite Editor: Can You Preview A Background Image While Setting Pivot?

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, sprite, unity-ui

I've Googled around a lot, and I checked the Unity Asset store but I cannot seem to find what I *think* is a common problem (or perhaps I'm doing it wrong).

The issue is when I use the Sprite Editor I cannot see a reference image which is useful for setting the sprite pivot.

When I open the Sprite Editor on a given image file, I cannot seem to add a background reference image:

[image]

I want to be able to see a background image (of a specific character for example) that I can position and then use that to set the pivot.

Do you know of any way to do this? Asset Store references are acceptable.

[I found one for Animation pivot setting](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/sprite-pivot-editor-39489) but not for static images.

Any and all suggestions welcome (if you have a workflow suggestion that mitigates this issue, feel free to suggest :) )

Comment: The [plugin](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/sprite-pivot-editor-39489) you linked says that it [works with individual sprites](https://d2ujflorbtfzji.cloudfront.net/package-screenshot/2bde8420-e099-463f-a406-9bae19ed8eaf_scaled.jpg). Are you sure that it doesn't meet your needs?

Comment: Ah interesting, perhaps this will work. I will consider purchasing this then. Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: One caveat seems to come from description, where its saying each item must have an Animator component: "This is an editor extension that run’s in the scene view, and any game object with an Animator component can use this extension as along as it deals with sprite animation. "

Comment: Yea its not really clear if actually just edits the root sprite pivot outside the animation.

Comment: If I go to its [thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/sprite-pivot-editor-a-complete-solution-to-all-of-your-sprite-alignment-setup.334010/), it then says, "You can also use this extension along with the Sprite Renderer component to modify the pivot point of whatever sprite it hold from within the scene as well."  There is a youtube video below the description that shows it doing that at 0:19.

Comment: Not a Unity solution and more a workaround but you might want to give [OnTopReplica](https://github.com/LorenzCK/OnTopReplica) a shot. You have to open the image in a simple Image Viewer Programm and than tell OnTopReplica to "clone" that window.

Comment: Ah thanks for the suggestion I will look at this as well

Comment: @Ruzihm Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a free option that works well enough:

http://gnupart.tistory.com/entry/Unity3D-Custom-Sprite-Pivot-Editor-in-SceneView